# Manual IPsec and session key(s)

Tags: key-management, ipsec

I am evaluating IPsec.

I have determined it is best for my case to *not use AH* (will use PSK for authentication).

One issue I have is that at the start there will be no connectivity, so IKE will not be usable; it would hang.  The solution I seem to have found is called "single key" (which I understand to be the PSK being the session key for the duration of the session ... many days, possibly many months) but I would like to do a key exchange as soon as I can, which is after I need to have authenticated (with PSK) IPsec working.  So I am thinking to not use AH, not use existing IKE implementations, starting like "single key", and run my own daemon to do a session key update/exchange soon and then periodically.  *Does this sound plausible/secure?*  This will be in Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS with Linux 3.13.0.  I can code things I might need in Bash, AWK, C, or Python.

*Edit:*

Looks like I might have to do a restart somehow.

Comment: Please use capitalization when you post.